# If TD-id == $var-date -> Display $var name tp specific td -Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, dynamic, calendar, laravel-5.3

Im having a hard time here.

I have a weekly calendar below. Each td has the ID of the date assigned for the days in a month.

[image]

What I want to do is to display these menus for each specific date that it matches in the calendar td

This is my menu table
[image]

I understand that I should format the menuDate to match the date in the td. I handled that in my eloquent query. Not included here

And this is my code in displaying the calendar

Controller:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Hong_Kong');
  $year = (isset($_GET['year'])) ? $_GET['year'] : date("Y");
  $week = (isset($_GET['week'])) ? $_GET['week'] : date('W');
  if($week > 52) {
      $year++;
      $week = 1;
  } elseif($week < 1) {
      $year--;
      $week = 52;
  }
```

View:

```
    <table class = "table">
    <tr>
      @if($week < 10)
        <?php
          $week = '0'. $week;
        ?>
      @endif

      @for($day= 1; $day <= 7; $day++)
        <?php
          $d = strtotime($year ."W". $week . $day);
          echo "<td = id '".date('y-m-d', $d)."'>"
                  .date('Md', $d) ."<br>". date('D', $d)
              ."</td>";
        ?>
      @endfor
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can someone help me on how should I do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to understand your question.

Comment: I want to display the menu item on the calendar. per specific date availability

Comment: Yes, I got that bit :) It was more to do with which bit specifically were you struggling with or which bit wasn't working. Either way, I added an example of what you could do.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Laravel you have access to `Carbon` which is like `DateTime` but loads of helper methods http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Also, with Laravel you have the `Request` which is used (among other things) can be used to get parameters from the request. You can also supply defaults for these. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#retrieving-input

Either way, you could do something like:

Controller method

```
public function yourMethod (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {

    $year = $request->input('year', date("Y"));
    $week = $request->input('week', date('W'));

    $date = \Carbon\Carbon::now('Asia/Hong_Kong')->setISODate($year, $week);

    return view('test', compact('date'));

}
```

Blade file

```
<table class = "table">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
       @for($day= 1; $day <= 7; $day++)

           <td id="{{ $date->format('Y-m-d') }}">
               {{ $date->format('M d') }} <br>
               {{ $date->format('D') }}
           </td>

           <?php $date->addDay() ?>
       @endfor
   </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!